# Relation between inner product and its real part.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, inner-products

Let  $\{, \} : V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ denote a Hermitian inner product on a vector space $V$ over the field of complex numbers
$\mathbb{C}$.

Let $\langle,\rangle: V\times V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ denote the real part of $\{,\}$.

I want to show that $\{v,w\}=\langle v,w\rangle- i\langle iv,w\rangle$

Any hints.

Comment: Note the proper use of angle brackets, as in my edit to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\Im \{v,w\} = \Re (-i \{v,w\}) = \langle -iv, w \rangle.$$