# Inner product and real structure

Tags: inner-products

Let $V$ be a complex vector space of dimension $n$ with a inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$. Is there any "inherited" inner space for $V$ seen as a $2n$-real vector space?  Is it just the real part $\Re(\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$?

Comment: It's the same inner product, you just don't see the complex conjugation since $\bar z = z$ for all $z \in \mathbb R$

Comment: But the same inner product can return a complex number @BrevanEllefsen, and to be a real inner product it must return a real number

Comment: Sure, because you are restricting your base field to $\mathbb R$. It's just like taking a complex polynomial and graphing it over the real line; you are restricting down the base field to the real numbers, so the conjugation "vanishes"

Comment: So it is the real part of the complex inner product?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415733/relation-between-inner-product-and-its-real-part

Comment: So it is the same thing that I just said?

Comment: I don't want to write up a proof, that answer has one, so I linked it.